# Implementing backdrop-filter: opacity(0%) in CSS

Tags: css, filter, transparency, opacity, alpha

In Cascading Style Sheet, I'm trying to implement the following:

`backdrop-filter: opacity(0%);`

As far as I can tell, it works, but is just boring a "hole" through every layer of elements behind it.

Is there a way to make the transparency stop at a certain element/layer?

Comment: Sensitive matter: https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/53

Comment: I'm not able to make it even do that, seems to not do anything for me. Do you have a demo where it makes the boring hole?

Comment: @waterplea yeah, seems like this behavior was a bug, and it's been fixed since

Answer (score 0):

This should be usefull, there is a handy demo as well
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/

Comment: Thank you, I've seen that article.  All of the other backdrop filters work great, the problem with "backdrop-filter: opacity(0%)" is that it literally just gives everything beneath it an opacity of 0.  I'm looking for a way to implement this more selectively, preventing one specific layer beneath from vanishing.  So far, nothing.